# Using Java Service Wrapper GUI to interact with desktop on windows

Tags: java, windows

Help!!

Please I created a Java Windows Service using Java Service Wrapper, now my Service is supposed to pop up a dialog at certain times and this doesn't seem to work.

I've tested the service before installing and it worked just fine, but after installing the service nothing happens.

Please how do I solve this issue?

Comment: You may need to post some code and give some more detail of the environment. Describe some of the things you checked. System logs etc.

Comment: you can't have a windows service with GUI for security reasons (except on XP)

Comment: you can try with JavaExe

Comment: ok thanks. that should be the reason @bb67

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use Java RMI, or something based on it: Jini, CORBA, remote OSGi, etc.
You should redesign your program according server-client architecture: windows service must be a client to gui app and call its methods to pop up proper widow in proper time. If you need callback from gui app to windows service you should also design the last as a client to the gui app.