# How to use Java RMI to control a desktop window from a Windows Service?

Tags: java, windows, rmi, jna, java-service-wrapper

I am having the same problem with this one >
[Using Java Service Wrapper GUI to interact with desktop on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615739/using-java-service-wrapper-gui-to-interact-with-desktop-on-windows)

I am currently using Java Service Wrapper to wrap my Java program into a Windows Service. It has a requirement to get hold of an open Window and control it (i.e. press buttons).

I have made it an interactive service and even installed it as an admin user and still no success.

I am using JNA library to get the Windows instance which always returns null if it is running as a service but successful when triggered manually.

```
hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(0, targetWindowTitle);
```

One comment in that thread says , it needs to use Java RMI. Do we have examples on how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What they meant was that if an interactive user started a Java GUI application that included an RMI service, the Java program running as a service could connect to it and send commands. Or vice versa.

Comment: So there is no chance that I could run a Windows Service > make this service interact with the open Windows?

Comment: No. If the interactive user runs your helper application, you can do it.

Comment: Start a desktop application which runs in the Windows tray. This application can then receive commands from the service (via whatever IPC method you want) to work with the desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that is not possible for security reason.

Take a look at the Java Service Wrapper `wrapper.ntservice.interactive` property documentation at https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html